# x-axis interval labeling for facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame:

```
dput(head(df))
structure(list(Year = c(1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998), 
type = c("PS", "PS", "PS", "PS", "PS", "PS"), measure = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), value = c(19034.33, 9550.89, 12934.76, 
10779.04, 7433.43, 7955.47)), .Names = c("Year", "type", 
"measure", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to plot the stacked area, however, I encountered a problem in labeling x-axis. 
The figure is as shown below:

[image]

For all the facets: Starting year is 1993 and end is 2016; The year is in numeric format.

I want to show all the year range(1993 to 2016) in the x-axis, despite having the blank data in facet C and D.

I used the following as suggested in the forum:

```
ggplot() + geom_area() + facet_wrap(~ measure, scales = "free_x")
```

However, this does not seem to work. How can this be resolved?

Comment: remove `scales = 'free_x'`

Comment: I have tried removing it, but it does not display all the year in x-axis

Comment: Thank you, @Jack Brookes, it works. This is easy now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide enough data to recreate your graph, but here's my answer

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    Year = c(1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998),
    type = c("PS", "PS", "PS", "PS", "PS", "PS"),
    measure = c("A",
                "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
    value = c(19034.33, 9550.89, 12934.76,
              10779.04, 7433.43, 7955.47)
  ),
  .Names = c("Year", "type",
             "measure", "value"),
  row.names = c(NA, 6L),
  class = "data.frame"
)


library(ggplot2)


ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = type)) +
  geom_area() +
  facet_wrap(~ measure) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1993:2016, limits = c(1993, 2016))
```

[image]